# Hitting pig bug in DataStax 4

Tags: apache-pig, datastax-enterprise

We upgraded to DataStax 4 and ran into this bug.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3120

We already have a work around in, do we need to wait on a new release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSE 4.0 only supports pig 0.10 release. Your fix is 0.12 release which is not included in  DSE 4.0. We may patch 0.10 and replace the jar bundled in DSE 4.0

Comment: When will that decision be made?